# Problems with image textures in Blender

Tags: texturing, uv, image, uv-image-editor

I am still fairly new to blender, and nothing frustrates me more than using image textures and UV unwrapping. I understand in theory how it should work, but every time I try it doesn't seem to happen the way it should. Iv every tutorial they unwrap the mesh, and bam a perfect result, yet I am getting results like this.

[image: Results]

[image: Wide]

If there is something simple that I'm not getting or that I'm doing wrong please help me to understand because it's driving me nuts!

Thanks!

Comment: Your leaf has [awful topology](http://topologyguides.com), ngons are bad for a number of reasons, including unwrapping as you already found out. Also if you are using an alpha texture there really is no need for your mesh shape to follow the texture so closely, it will only add unnecessary geometric complexity.

Comment: Just like Duarte said- there's no need for an extra geometry here. Add a *simple plane*, unwrap it, then map a texture on it. That's all.

Comment: All you need  is a simple plane and use the alpha channel to create the transparent outline of your object. Read the following link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90389/why-bump-node-giving-stretched-results/90412#90412

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21031/object-contours-in-depth-maps/21040#21040 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/image-alpha-background-renders-black-when-using-import-images-as-planes/27635#27635